# I can't connect to the internet when i share my hotspot on computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping

When I enable my hotspot in my computer, devices that have access to my hotspot can connect to the Internet, but they cannot ping other IP addresses in the network. However, my computer loses access to the Internet once I share the hotspot, but it can ping other IP addresses, even Google's DNS server!
I would like to connect to the internet and access certain servers on my network, which is currently not possible.

If anyone can help me solve this problem, I would be grateful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your Hotspot is on a different subnet than your main network and is almost for sure a double NAT arrangement.

Use your Hotspot when you need to and it is limited to the device you are using.

Otherwise, turn your Hotspot OFF and use your regular connection. You cannot use both at the same time.

Comment: And what exactly can cause such a problem, knowing that I was using my hotspot normally without any such problem and no changes were made on my local network?

Comment: Jus do not use two network connections at the same time. Disconnect regular to use Hotspot.

Comment: And what exactly can cause such a problem  ....   It is as I said likely two different subnets.